# Proper use of FOR statement

Tags: vbscript, for-loop

I'm looking for a comprehensive use of the FOR statement for VBS... trying to integrate a statement using FOR.

This is just for fun, but wondering what sites other people use for VBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this site: 
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_looping.asp

kinda basic, but they have a lot of good information on there.

Also, if you're just learning this site is pretty good for beginners:
http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Teach-Yourself-VBScript-in-21-Days/

Comment: ahh, thanks man! ya... I think we've all been there... I'm still trying to learn VBS

Answer (score 1):

I like the use of "for each x in array" to quickly enum all given options:

```
For Each personalityCore in array("Morality", "Curiosity", "Intelligence", "Anger")
    MsgBox "Sadly enough you just destroyed my " & personalityCore & " Core!"
Next
```

Another use is the (in)famous for/select loop:

```
For i = 0 to ubound(actionsToDo)
    Select Case actionsToDo(i)
        Case "Work"
            StartWorking
        Case "Play"
            StartPlaystation3
        Case Else
            ' Do Nothing
    End Select
Next
```